# How to securely encrypt a string in R?

Tags: r, encryption

How to securely encrypt a string in R so that it is impossible to do reverse 
decryption?

---

Update @11/21/2019

I do not want a key to encrypt the string.

The goal is that even someone can look into my code and the encrypted string, they will not be able to retrieve the original string.

---

I am using openssl package, shown as below

```
library(openssl)

md5("example")
```

---

*Please note that the question has been changed according to the comment from James, the original question is **What is the most secure way to encrypt a string in R?***

Comment: In my opinion, almost any question that starts out "What is the most secure..." is automatically too broad. Worse yet, after a few years the answers become obsolete and possibly dangerously wrong.

Comment: Thanks James, I will update my question to be more precise

Comment: I presume you mean "impossible to do reverse decryption **without the key**"

Comment: Hi Hugh, I have updated the description of the question

Answer (score 7):

I'm a fan of `sodium`:

```r
library(sodium)
passkey <- sha256(charToRaw("password123"))
plaintext <- "example"
plaintext.raw <- serialize(plaintext, NULL)
ciphertext <- data_encrypt(plaintext.raw, key = passkey)
unserialize(data_decrypt(ciphertext, key = sha256(charToRaw("password123"))))
#> [1] "example"
```

<sup>Created on 2019-11-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

In terms of whether it's the "most secure", the underlying method should be good enough, even for highly classified information. But the security of how the `passkey` is stored, entered, or communicated is likely to be the weak point.

Comment: PBKDF is a different kettle of fish.